# ffmpeg - video from single image with (multiple) video overlays

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i'm using the following ffmpeg command to generate a (15s) video from a single image

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280:720 out.mp4
```

The second command takes the/a video and adds multiple video overlays.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.m4v -vf "movie=movie.m4v, scale=140:-1[inner]; movie=movie.m4v, scale=100:-1[inner2]; [in][inner] overlay=70:70 [step1]; [step1][inner2] overlay=300:70 [out]" out.mp4
```

Does anybody know how to combine these two lines into one single command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Video only

You can use one filtergraph for all filtering.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image0.png -i video1.m4v -i video2.m4v -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:-2[bg]; \
 [1:v]scale=140:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg1]; \
 [2:v]scale=100:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg2]; \
 [bg][fg1]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[ol]; \
 [ol][fg2]overlay=300:70,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- The [`movie`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) multimedia source filter is not required.
- [`setpts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) will reset the timestamp so it works better with [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).
- Note the `shortest=1` in one of the overlay filters. Otherwise the image input will loop forever. Alternatively you could use the [`trim`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) filter on the image input.
- The "end of file" action of `overlay` can be changed with `eof_action`.
- The [`format` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) will set compatible chroma subsampling for QuickTime and other crappy players.
- When encoding is finished `-movflags +faststart` will relocate some data to the beginning of the file. This is useful, for example, if you are outputting to MP4 and your viewers will watch via progressive download such as from a browser.

## With audio

Assuming both videos have stereo audio and you wanted to combine audio from each video into a single stereo output.

### Example 1

[image]

This example will place both input left channels into the output left channel, and both input right channels into the output right channel.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image0.png -i video1.m4v -i video2.m4v -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:-2[bg]; \
 [1:v]scale=140:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg1]; \
 [2:v]scale=100:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg2]; \
 [bg][fg1]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[ol]; \
 [ol][fg2]overlay=300:70,format=yuv420p[v]; \
 [1:a][2:a]amerge[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

### Example 2

[image]

This example will place both channels from the first input into the left channel of the output, and both channels from the second input into the right channel of the output.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image0.png -i video1.m4v -i video2.m4v -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:-2[bg]; \
 [1:v]scale=140:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg1]; \
 [2:v]scale=100:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg2]; \
 [bg][fg1]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[ol]; \
 [ol][fg2]overlay=300:70,format=yuv420p[v]; \
 [1:a][2:a]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

### Example 3

If you just want the audio from one input, then just add a `-map` option to the video example above (no need for `amerge` and `pan`):

```
-map 1:a -c:a copy
```

## Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Audio Encoding](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)